# Unable to open Edge Browser using custom user agent and profile using command arguments in subprocess.call()

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, microsoft-edge, python-os

I am trying to open Microsoft Edge using mobile agent and profile, but am unable to. The Microsoft Edge does open but still uses default string. I have tried various methods to do it but none works. I am able to open Edge with desired profile though.

These are what I tried:

Putting whole target into one line.

```
subprocess.call('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe --profile-directory="Profile 3" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SCH-I535 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"')
```

And by passing an array of executable and two arguments.,

```
subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe', '--profile-directory="Profile 3"', '--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SCH-I535 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"'])
```

As well as passing variables storing the arguments:

```
edgeLink = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe'
profile3 = '--profile-directory="Profile 3"'
userString = '--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SCH-I535 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"'

subprocess.call([edgeLink, profile3, userString])
```

But nothing seems to work for me. I have tried looking online but nothing seems to help my use case. I did find one article that said, Google chrome has remove user string, but I am not sure if that is what affecting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this line:

```
subprocess.call('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe --profile-directory="Profile 3" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SCH-I535 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"')
```

works fine to use custom user agent and profile. You just need to **kill all the msedge.exe processes** to activate the command line options. You can try the following command to kill them:

```
taskkill /f /im msedge.exe
```

And here's my user agent after running `subprocess.call()`:
[image]

Comment: I disabled the edge startup boost, and it started working fine. It was messing up since edge would still run in background even if exited